# how to display a php webpage in android web view

Tags: java, android, webview

i am trying to display a php webpage(a webcam stream) inside a Webview for an android app that im trying to make (im new to java and android).[thats the xml and where i want the stream to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFMi8.png)

here is my java code i made from the info i got from developers.google but it does not seem to work

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.roomSelector);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.available_Rooms, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webvieww);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.google.com")) {

            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

[also a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdKGa.png)

can somebody help me with showing that php stream into that WebView or is there any other way to show the stream (i dont want to use sockets). i wan to display the webpage inside the webview in the picture above

Comment: Please add your logcat.

Comment: looks like you're missing ```webView.loadUrl("http://your-url.here")```
And what MyWebViewClient should do?